# i will try to connect database using pdo in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pdo

```
$db['default']['hostname'] ='mysql:host=myhostname;dbname=test;' ; 
$db['default']['username'] ='root';
$db['default']['password'] ='';        
$db['default']['database'] ='test';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] ='pdo';
```

Message: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Comment: How about trying to format your code as well.

Comment: @hasnain replace host=myhostname; with host='localhost';

Comment: i'll did it already but still not working

Comment: Try 127.0.0.1 as the hostname?

Comment: @spudmonkee why not add your comment as an answer, so this thread can be marked and move from unanswered quees.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile there we go :).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$hostname='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=stickercollections",$username,$password);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
// <== add this line
echo 'Connected to Database<br/>';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM stickercollections";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
{
    echo $row["collection_brand"] ." - ". $row["collection_year"] ."<br/>";
}


$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `127.0.0.1` as your host name.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong already in your very first line....

$db['default']['hostname'] ='mysql:host=myhostname;dbname=test;' ;

['hostname'] is just 'myhostname'

The field you need is 
`$db['default']['dsn'] = 'mysql:host=myhostname;dbname=test'`

No ; here as options below will be concatenated.